# Noun form of "analytic"

Tags: nouns

I've been tasked with creating some custom website tracking for a CMS, similar to Google Analytics. I was going to title this area on the back-end as *Analytics* but I got a spell-check red squiggle and that sent me to a Google search which resulted in me finding out *analytics* isn't a real word.

So is there a noun form of *analytic* or am I just being stupid?

Comment: "Google Analytics" is a brand name, maybe based a longer phrase ("Google Analytic Tools"?) which they wanted to shorten for marketing purposes. It sounds like the coinage of "electronics" for "electronic devices or components".

Comment: Is there an *analytic*, in the noun sense of someone who likes to analyze things?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It absolutely *is* a word.

From [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/analytics):

> an·a·lyt·ics
>   noun pl but singular or pl in constr \ˌa-nə-ˈli-tiks\
>   : the method of logical analysis
>   First Known Use of ANALYTICS
>   circa 1590

Comment: Weird, I couldn't find it anywhere. Not in the OALD nor the NOAD.

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally, the noun form is *analysis*. The *-sis* ending in Greek is a noun form that gets changed into *-ikos* when it is made into an adjective, from which we get out *-ic* ending for lots of our adjectives. The word *analytics* was perhaps coined a very long time ago, but it has only recently been gaining currency, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Oxford Advanced Learner’s Dictionary 2000 at hand (though it’s a bit old edition), only shows “analytic” as an adjective to mean (1) using a logical method of thinking about sth in order to understand it, and (2) using scientific analysis in order to find out sth, and “analytically” as an adverb. Cambridge Dictionary (online) doesn’t give “analytic,” but “analytical.” Both dictionaries don’t cite the word, “analytics.” Kenkyusha’s Readers aEnglish Japanese Dictionary shows “analyticity” as a noun form of “analytic.”

Though Google NGam shows gradually increasing trend of its (analytics) use (from 0.000001% in 1880 to 0.000014%) as compared with “statistics” (0.001% in 1880 to 0.0025% in 2000), the receptivity of “analytics” doesn’t seem to be in equal level as economics, physics, and statistics. I personally think it’s better for you to let Google be a single user of unfamiliar “Analytics” for their product for the moment.